# Making programs depending on interpreter lib portable

Tags: haskell, runtime, interpreter

Consider this simple program using the "hint" library:

```
import qualified Language.Haskell.Interpreter as Hint

main :: IO ()
main = Hint.runInterpreter interpreter >>= print

interpreter :: Hint.Interpreter Int
interpreter = do
  Hint.setImports ["Prelude"]
  Hint.interpret "2 + 3" 0
```

You can see that to be able to use the `+` function in the interpreted code I need the `Prelude` module to be imported by the interpreter. As I understand the interpreter imports it from the "base" library located in a local repository, so I expect it to throw some kinda runtime exception if this executable gets run on a machine with no Haskell Platform, where there is no local repository.

If I am correct in my assumption, is there a solution or a workaround, which will make this program portable? In fact I am looking for a general solution to interpreting arbitrary code, not necessarily depending just on the modules of "base" package, ability to import  modules of the project is also needed.

Comment: Please note you need not have Haskell platform installed to have `Prelude`. It comes directly with GHC for instance. I supposed it's the same for other compilers.

Comment: Sounds doubtful. Where did you get that info?

Comment: This seems simple to test (have you yet?), but more than a little hard to work around if it doesn't work. There's a chance that the [hint server](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint-server) package could resolve that, but it's not clear whether that's portable itself!

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Download GHC and see for yourself (in `libraries/base/`)

Comment: @enoughreptocomment Nope, [according to the very simple source of Hint Server](https://github.com/elbrujohalcon/hint-server/blob/master/src/Language/Haskell/Interpreter/Server.hs#L32), all it does is makes the interpreter import "Prelude" the same way as in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's impossible. Running a compiled program on a linux machine without Haskell fails with the following message:

```
/usr/lib/ghc/settings: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

So, the interpreter library explicitly depends on the local GHC.